# Define specific TTL for each interfaces

Tags: ipv6, interface, ipv4

After some research, I was wondering if it was possible to define a TTL by interface as I can the Hop Limit definition in ipv6.

To change the TTL in IPv4, I can change the file

```
 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
```

But this changes TTL for all interfaces.

However in IPv6, you can put a different hop limit value for each interfaces

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth*/hop_limit
```

So do I miss something? or there is no way to configure a different TTL for each interface ?

Comment: please visit this extenstion of iptables: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO.html#toc3.20

Comment: Thank you, but I find my solution with warl0ck answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that entry does not exist for ipv4, it's probably not supported.

But have you tried to modify TTL values with iptables? [See if the `TTL` target helps](http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4799.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I supposed too that it is not supported and I'm looking for a trick to do that. I will look at your link.

Comment: I will use iptables to do what I want, especially that I need to specify TTL by protocols. So very useful link, thank you.